# How to change size of UIView in collection view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I have set up several collection views and when I am generating each cell I want to show change size of specific view controllers. My code looks like this:

```
    YCFrequencyMonthCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"graphMonth" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.MonthLabel.text = self.graphDataArray[indexPath.row - 3];

    UIView *sentView = cell.graphMonthlySentView;
    CGRect sentFrame;
    sentFrame.size.width = 50;
    sentView.frame = sentFrame;

    return cell;
```

I get no errors and do not know why it doesn't work. It seemed to work when I was doing it outside of CollectionViewController.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "when I am generating each cell I want to show change size of specific view controllers".
2. Here you take CGRect structure, then set only the width property, then set it to the sentView's frame ? it's not right.
The thing seems to me that you wanna set the width of the view to 50, to do that you need `CGRect sentFrame = sentView.frame;` then you set it's width to 50 and then `sentView.frame = sentFrame;`

Comment: I did the following: `CGRect sentFrame = cell.graphMonthlySentView.frame;
        sentFrame.size.width = 50;
        cell.graphMonthlySentView.frame = sentFrame;` But it still doesn't seem to work. Am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: set the graphMonthlySentView's Frame width to 50 inside the Cell class's layoutSubViews method. layoutSubView method reference is given here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews

Comment: So in Cell class I have added `- (void)layoutSubviews {    
    [super layoutSubviews];    
    CGRect sentFrame = self.graphMonthlySentView.frame;
    sentFrame.size.width = 150;
    self.graphMonthlySentView.frame = sentFrame;
}` but this doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: are you using any king of GUI thing xib / storybaord, the please disable the autolayout feature from the xib / storyboard, go to the File inspector in interface builder, and untick "Use Auto Layout".

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!!! All along ... Thank you soooo much Ratul !!!!!!

Comment: Thats my pleasure :)